# Would Japanese happoshu or third-category beer be considered beer in other countries?

Tags: terminology

In Japan, beer is classified in three types for taxation purposes: beer (66.6% of more of malt), happoshu ( under 66.6% malt and no added liqueur), third-type beer (contain some added liquerur)

Would happoshu be considered beer in other countries?

Comment: Is that 66.6% a proportion of malt in the wort? What are the other igredients of remaining 33.3%?

Comment: Hi there @doc, sorry, but I've got no clues of the other igredients of happoshu or their recicpies...

Comment: The definition of happoshu on the Japanese Law is: sparkling liquor made of barley or malt that alcohol content is less than 20%. (My translation)

Answer (score 1):

Well in Germany these wouldn't be called beer because in Germany beer can contain only malt, hop, water and yeast. Since many Asian beers contain rice these aren't called beer in Germany.
I don't know if other countries even have regulations whether a drink is allowed to call itself beer.